# Require a stream in browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

For a few reasons I have a use case for browserify where I am running it programmatically on a dynamic set of stream inputs.

This generally has been working fine in cases like

```
var a, b; // objects that contain streams of javascript

var brwsrfy = browserify();
brwsrfy.require(a.stream, {expose: a.name, basedir: ...});
brwsrfy.require(b.stream, {expose: b.name, basedir: ...});
brwsrfy.bundle();
```

and then I am able to `require('a')`, `require('b')`, etc in later scripts. However, I have come to a case where one of my dynamic streams wants to `require('a')`. But this currently throws an error because it is looking for a file `a.js` in the basedir, but it really just needs to require the stream `a`.

Is there any way to tell browserify to lookup a stream for that particular require instead of looking for a file?

Edit: I should add that I have access to the names of everything that is being `expose`'d, so maybe some kind of custom transform that looks specifically for `require`s on those names and does... something?